# В чем разница между ссache и make?

Tags: makefile

Недавно узнал о такой программе как ссache.

> Выдержка из Википедии:
>
> Использование ссache может значительно ускорить сборку некоторых
>   пакетов или проектов, которые компилируются несколько раз, так как
>   заново компилироваться будут только файлы, которые изменились с
>   последней компиляции.

В чем преимущество ссache перед make в плане данного пункта (или есть другие преимущества)?

В каких случаях применяется ccache?

Comment: краткий ответ: это совершенно разные программы. сравнивать бессмысленно: оне **не** взаимозаменимы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin столкнувшись с данной программой я не понимаю, зачем ее вообще использовать, если есть make. Поэтому и хотелось бы узнать, может кто-то использует для чего-то. Зацепила фраза "значительно ускорить сборку", однако те механизмы, которые видны, на первый взгляд, не лучше make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

краткий ответ: это совершенно разные программы. сравнивать их бессмысленно: оне **не** взаимозаменимы.

---

### чуть более длинный ответ:

программа *make* вообще не имеет отношения к компиляторам, а программа *ccache* — это [кэш компилятора для языков C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++](http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_description). стандартный способ её применения — «подмена» компилятора (например, с [помощью создания символических ссылок вида `/usr/local/bin/cc`](http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_run_modes)).

[*The basic idea is to detect when you are compiling exactly the same code a second time and reuse the previously produced output.*](http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_how_ccache_works) (мой вольный перевод: *базовая идея — определить, когда вы компилируете тот же самый код во второй раз, и воспользоваться уже готовым результатом*).

---

### совсем упрощённо, без нюансов и деталей

в процессе компиляции создаётся т.н. [*объектный модуль* (*объектный файл*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C). например, в результате выполнения `cc -c файл.c` будет получен `файл.o`

который впоследствии может быть использован [*компоновщиком* (*линковщиком*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA) для создания исполняемого файла с программой.

довольно часто исполняемый файл компонуется из несколькоих объектных модулей. и если мы «в лоб» автоматизируем этот процесс (`cc -c файл1.c && cc -c файл2.c && cc файл1.o файл2.o -o программа`), то при каждом вызове этой длинной команды будут вновь и вновь компилироваться **все** файлы с исходными текстами, даже если мы внесли изменение, например, лишь в один из них.

чтобы избежать повторной компиляции *не изменявшихся* файлов, можно воспользоваться, например, программой *make*, которая не занимается, собственно, компиляцией, но помогает избежать выполнения повторных действий там, где это не требуется. ну, при наличии соответствующих правил в *makefile*, где будут описаны зависимости между файлами и способы обновления тех файлов, которые требуют обновления.

пример таких правил:

- если `файл.c` новее `файл.o`, то выполнить команду `cc -c файл.c`
- если `файл.o` новее `программа`, то выполнить команду `cc файл.o -o программа`

всё это замечательно работает, если у нас один проект (и объектные файлы не удаляются после компиляции). а если проектов несколько, и во всех из них (или хотя бы в некоторых) используется `файл.c` с идентичным содержимым? программа *make* тут не поможет избежать множественных компиляций одного и того же файла в **разных** проектах.

вот тут нам может помочь упомянутая программа *ccache* (если «подменить» ею программу `cc`).

алгоритм прост:

1. если переданный файл до сих пор не компилировался, то скомпилировать его, вызвав «настоящий» `cc`, и скопировать результат (объектный модуль) в кэш.
2. если переданный файл уже компилировался, то скопировать из кэша готовый объектный модуль.

[*The detection is done by hashing different kinds of information that should be unique for the compilation and then using the hash sum to identify the cached output.*](http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_how_ccache_works) (мой вольный перевод: *для определения, что файл «тот же самый», используется [хэширование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) различных видов информации, которая должна быть уникальна для данной компиляции, и эти хэш-суммы позволяют вычислить, какой именно из закэшированных результатов следует использовать*).

Answer (score 0):

Преимущество `ccache` как раз в процитированном вами поведении. `make` каждый раз при сборке пакета выполняет компиляцию заново. `ccache`, в отличии от `make`, перед компиляцией смотрит - а может быть эта работа уже сделана? И если какой-то файл уже был скомпилирован, то повторно его компиляция не выполняется, а берётся уже скомпилированный ранее результат. Разумеется `ccache` достаточно умён что бы отследить, что хотя файл и был скомпилирован ранее, но сейчас в нём появились изменения и потому нужна повторная компиляция.

> В каких случаях он применяется?

В тех, когда регулярно приходится перекомпилировать одни и те же программы и есть желание ускорить этот процесс. Например `ccache` крайне полезен в дистрибутиве Gentoo, где установка программ как раз и заключается в их компиляции из исходных кодов.

Comment: make также проверяет, был ли изменен файл и не перекомпилирует неизмененные файлы. Также перекомпиляция возможна при изменении включенного заголовочного файла. Исходя из этого и ставился вопрос... Не видны различия - у make гораздо выше функционал.

Comment: *при сборке пакета* — вероятно, стоит конкретизировать, что именно подразумевается в данном случае под словом «пакет». и привести информацию о том, почему именно программа make в данном конкретном случае не способна выполнить то, для чего она, собственно, и написана: обновлять только те цели, которые старше пререквизитов.